# Maximum cliques of the transitive closure of a chordal DAG

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, clique, transitive-closure

Let $G=(V,A)$ be a directed acyclic graph, for which the underlying
undirected graph is chordal (so that every induced cycle in the
underlying undirected graph is a triangle).

It is known that in a chordal graph the number of *maximum cliques*
is linearly bounded in the number $|V|$ of vertices.

Let $G'=(V,A')$ be the transitive closure of $G$, so that for
every directed path $p= (v_i,\ldots,v_j)$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$
in $G$, there exists a directed edge $(v_i,v_j)$ in $A'$.

> **Question:** Is there any polynomial/linear bound on the number
> of maximum cliques in the undirected graph that underlies $G'$?

Comment: You are right, but that is a description of the structure of $G$, independent of the edge orientation.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can extend Vinicius dos Santos' idea to show that no polynomial bound is possible.

Consider a graph on $n$ vertices divided into $d\geq 1$ groups of size about $n/d$ as follows:

[image]

Its transitive closure has about $(\frac{n}{d})^d$ maximal (undirected) cliques.

Comment: @Laakeri Then I must have my definitions mixed up somehow, it seems chordal to me :/

Comment: I'm sorry, of course it's a chordal graph. Somehow I didn't see the edge in the middle.

Comment: @Laakeri All good!

Answer (score 1):

A linear bound is impossible. Suppose your graph is a star, with half of the edges oriented towards the universal vertex $u$ and the rest oriented outward. In the transitive closure, the maximal cliques will be triangles, each of them containing $u$ and exactly one of its inneighbors and one of its outneighbors. This gives a quadratic number of maximal (and maximum) cliques.